# Cannot use QUrl

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwebenginepage

I am trying to learn Dynamic Web scraping on PyQt5. I was looking up the tutorials meant for PyQt4 so have some different libraries in Qt5.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

class Client(QWebEnginePage):
    def _init_(self, url):
        self.app=QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage._init_(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.on_page_load)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()
    def on_page_load(self):
        self.app.quit()

url='https://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface/'
client_response=Client(url)
source=client_response.mainFrame().toHtml()

#sauce=urllib.request.urlopen('https://pythonprogramming.net/sitemap.xml').read()
soup=bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'xml')
js_test=soup.find('p',class_='jstest')
print(js_test.text)
```

The following error is being show:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jsp.py", line 19, in <module>
    client_response=Client(url)
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QWebEnginePage(parent: QObject = None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'
  QWebEnginePage(QWebEngineProfile, parent: QObject = None): argument 1 has unexpected
```

Someone help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several errors:

- init must have 2 underscores before and after.
- `QWebEnginePage` does not have a `mainFrame()` as a method, now you have to load it directly
- Another change that arose was that the `toHtml()` function is no longer synchronous so it will ask you for a callback to get the html, but with my modification it is again synchronous.

**Code:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, pyqtSignal, QEventLoop
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage

class Client(QWebEnginePage):
    toHtmlFinished = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app=QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.on_page_load)
        self.load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def on_page_load(self):
        self.app.quit()

    def store_html(self, html):
        self.html = html
        self.toHtmlFinished.emit()

    def get_html(self):
        self.toHtml(self.store_html)
        loop = QEventLoop()
        self.toHtmlFinished.connect(loop.quit)
        loop.exec_()
        return self.html

url='https://pythonprogramming.net/parsememcparseface/'
client_response=Client(url)
source=client_response.get_html()

print(source)
```

References:

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebenginewidgets-qtwebkitportingguide.html
- [Is there any way to call synchronously the method 'toHtml' which is QWebEnginePage's object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47067050/pyqt5-9-is-there-any-way-to-call-synchronously-the-method-tohtml-which-is-qw/47067553#47067553)